# Extract plist from Simulator directory to use with my project during loads/saves

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I'm using a plist to store bookmarks as a simple array of strings.

I can load a plist from my project directory with no problem, but when I make changes to the plist it doesn't show up on the file in my project directory. Instead, the changes to the plist are being saved in a temporary directory used by the simulator.

Is there anyway to tell xcode to use the plist that's in the project directory?

When I run the app again my saved changes to this plist file are not seen since it loads the data from the project directory, then saves it again to the temp simulator folder.

Comment: It sounds like you are loading a file from the bundle, and then saving it to the documents directory. What is the temp directory it is being saved to?

Comment: yes Im loading from NSBundle mainBundle, I suppose I shouldn't being doing that, should i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand the app should **change** the contents of the plist. If that's the case, you should not load the file from the projects-directory. Those files are not to be changed once the app is shipped.

Instead, you should load and save the plist file in the Documents/ directory of your app bundle. That way, it will also be synced with iCloud if you want it to.

So, do something like ... if there's no file in the Documents/ directory, copy it to Documents/ from the bundle (assuming there are some default values in it). If there is a file, load it from Documents/ and work with it.

Comment: You think it would be just as easy to hide the array in a settings bundle?

Comment: uhhmm I *think* you could do that, but it's not really standard you know? The settings bundle is used by the settings.app to configure your app, you shouldn't use it for user data like bookmarks. Bear in mind that you cannot "hide" things anyway, if the user jailbreaks his phone, he has access to the file no matter what (however I don't see why one would want to see the file directly)